# MySQL - creating table with not null on multiple columns together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, check-constraints

Is there anyway to create a table with multiple columns and 2 of them should never be null in same record.

for example, I need to make `C` and `D` somehow that each one of them could be `null` if the other wasn't `null` in same record.

I there any way?

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
```

**And they should never have value together**

Comment: Question is a bit wierd.. But you can can handle this user case with a trigger.

Comment: I removed the php and mysqli tags, because the question does not pertain to PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints, as @lad2025 mentioned. You can do this with a trigger, as @RaymondNijland commented.

Here's what it might look like (tested on MySQL 5.6.37):

```
mysql> DELIMITER ;;

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER not_both_null BEFORE INSERT ON a_table_with_multiple_columns 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.c IS NULL AND NEW.d IS NULL) THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'One of C and D must be non-null';
    END IF;
  END ;;

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> insert into a_table_with_multiple_columns set c=null, d=null;                                                                                                                      
ERROR 1644 (45000): One of C and D must be non-null
```

Remember to create a similar trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` to check for the invalid condition, or else invalid data can sneak in via UPDATE after the row has been created.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it using `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(i INT PRIMARY KEY,
                 a INT,
                 b INT,
                 c INT,
                 d INT 
                 CHECK (NOT(c IS NULL AND d IS NULL))
                 );
```

**[DBFiddle Demo-MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cf0ef9cbf03d80cbe2c97467672a2944)**

```
INSERT INTO tab(i,a,b,c,d) 
VALUES(1,1,1,NULL,NULL);
-- error: CONSTRAINT `d` failed for `tab`

INSERT INTO tab(i,a,b,c,d) 
VALUES(2,1,1,1,NULL);
-- ok

INSERT INTO tab(i,a,b,c,d) 
VALUES(3,1,1,NULL,1);
-- ok

INSERT INTO tab(i,a,b,c,d) 
VALUES(4,1,1,1,1);
-- ok
```

Unfortunately in MySQL [create-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> **The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.**